# Angular not giving current state of checkbox

Tags: angular

I have started building an ToDo sample app. I am facing an strange issue.
Below is the HTML code for the ToDo List. In that list i am setting ngModel for checkbox and firing an change event as well.

[image]

Code to listen the change. I am only printing the current state to console.

[image]

Look at below image you can see the current state of the checkbox is checked but in console i am getting the previous state of the checkbox.

[image]

Please tell me what is the correct approach to have that working.

Comment: @dfsq here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sJYpaF0KG6yt9XUqW4EF?p=preview), I think on change event gets fired first while dealing with checkbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>This is a known issue</strike>

This is working as intended. When the change event is emitted `ngModelChange` (the `(...)` part of `[(ngModel)]` hasn't updated the bound model yet:

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406,
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311

There are different workarounds like using `event.target.value` instead of the value from the model.