# Angular 2 change event - model changes

Tags: angular

How can I get the values after a model has changed? The `(change)` event does fire before the model change. I do not want to use `event.target.value`

```
<input type="checkbox"  (change)="mychange(event)" [(ngModel)]="mymodel">

public mychange(event)
{
   console.log(mymodel); // mymodel has the value before the change
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 not giving current state of checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872843/angular-2-not-giving-current-state-of-checkbox)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

<strike>That's a known issue. Currently you have to use a workaround like shown in your question.</strike>

This is working as intended. When the change event is emitted `ngModelChange` (the `(...)` part of `[(ngModel)]` hasn't updated the bound model yet:

```html
<input type="checkbox"  (ngModelChange)="myModel=$event" [ngModel]="mymodel">
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406,
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311

Comment: Note that Gunter uses `(ngModelChange)` wrapped in parentheses -- not just `ngModelChange`

Comment: Too bad that `ngModelChange` is now deprecated. [Check it here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts)

Comment: Thats just a property from `FormControlName` directive https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts#L128 The `ngModelChange` from `NgModel` is not deprecated https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L193

Comment: @MTZ I think that `ngModelChange` is only deprecated in reactive forms and not in template-driven forms.

Comment: The workaround I ussualy use is 
setTimeout(()=>{ ... read updated model...},0)

Answer (score 52):

If this helps you,

```
<input type="checkbox"  (ngModelChange)="mychange($event)" [ngModel]="mymodel">

mychange(val)
{
   console.log(val); // updated value
}
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, but I can see why Gunter's was the chosen answer, because he points out that `(change)` is different, as said in his github issues; "click is a DOM event, not related to the higher level ngModel. The proper event for this is ngModelChange."

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
<input 
  (input)="$event.target.value = toSnakeCase($event.target.value)"
  [(ngModel)]="table.name" />
```

In Typescript

```
toSnakeCase(value: string) {
  if (value) {
    return value.toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]+/g, "");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `(ngModelChange)` event to detect changes on the model