# Updating array model deselects iterated <Input> elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

Trying to implement a add/remove sub-item entry; increment/decrement buttons add slots into the array and input fields are added/removed automatically:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsInNewOrder; let i = index">
  <input [(ngModel)]="itemsInNewOrder[i]" xtype="text" name="order" title="order" />
</div>
```

This is working functionally, but every time a letter is entered into the input, the element is deselected and must be clicked again to enter yet one more letter. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer to this was that I needed to learn and implement Angular 2's `reactive forms` library, which is part of Angular 2. Using this, I ran into none of difficulties I was experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

The link above explains change detection in Angular 2. It also describes some other change detection strategies that you might find useful.

Basically since you did a 2 way binding `[(ngModel)]="itemsInNewOrder[i]"` to the `itemsInNewOrder` array, Angular is trying to be helpful and update the view for you.

1. Each keystroke updates your model (itemsInNewOrder)
2. Angular detects the update
3. Angular renders the view again with new form controls
4. Again, these are new form controls so the user hasn't focused one yet. This is why you have to click into the control after every entered character.

You can fix this by removing your 2 way binding and instead listening to the blur event for each input or implementing something described in the link above.

Blur event listening example:

```
<input (blur)="blurHandler(item,i)" type="text" name="order" title="order" />
```

Component

```
blurHandler(val:string,ndx:number) {
  this.itemsInNewOrder[ndx] = val;
}
```

This might help too

[Angular 2 change event - model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150107/angular-2-change-event-model-changes)

Comment: Didn't work, I think because those html commands are still being watched by the changedetector. Yet after detatching, making operations, and reattatching, the data gets removed and the UI updated. Still at a loss. I can't imagine that making nested inputs is a new endeavor but I'm unable to find any mention of this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap the values into objects. I don't know why you don't lose focus if you do it like this.

Component:

```
itemsInNewOrder = [{value: 'Soda'}, {value: 'Burger'}, {value: 'Fries'}];
```

template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemsInNewOrder; let i = index">
    <input 
      type="text" 
      name="order" 
      title="order" 
      [(ngModel)]="itemsInNewOrder[i].value"/>
  </div>
```