# Angular4 "change" listener only fires once

Tags: javascript, angular, addeventlistener, lifecycle

I have a selection dropdown that I'm drawing data from that changes based on the selection. It will fire fine on first load, but wont change again until I reload or redirect.

```
    getLogs(){
  document.getElementById("placeSelect").addEventListener('change', (e:any)=>{
    this.placeService.getPlace(e.target.value).subscribe((e:any)=>{        
      this.personService.person(e.data.place.person.id).subscribe((e:any) => {
        this.logs = e.data.person.logs
      })
    })
  })

}
```

I am calling this on the component's "ngOnInit", maybe that's the issue? Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: forget about event listeners. in template, put `select (change)="onChangeHandler($event)"...>` and then in your component have method `onChangeHandler(event)`

Comment: See this link would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150107/angular-2-change-event-model-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the advice, but I managed a work around. The biggest hurdle is that the select was in a different component (which I apologize for failing to mention) so I had to export the select information to my component where the info would be displayed.

**component2.ts**

```
import { userInfo } from '../../component1';
```

And then a set a delay so that it would initiate the listen after both components are fully loaded. It seems it was firing before in my previous version

```
ngOnInit() {
if(userInfo.place){
  this.getLogsfromPlace()
}    
setTimeout(()=>{
  this.startupUserInfo = userInfo
  document.getElementById("header").addEventListener('change', (e:any)=>{
  this._placeService.getPlace(userInfo.place).subscribe((e:any)=>{
    this._personService.person(e.data.place.person.id).subscribe((e:any) => {
      this.logs = e.data.person.logs
    })
  })
})  }, 3000);
}
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you.

**Add this code in imports of Module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [FormsModule]
```

**Inside component.ts**

```
 myModel(e: Event) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

**In Component.html**

```
   <select (ngModelChange)="myModel($event)" [ngModel]="mymodel">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I guess I should've clarified. My apologies. But the select and where the data is being displayed is on two separate components.