# Ngmodel value is updating wrongly?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

**I have using one third party dropdown and calender component, if i change value ngmodel value is updating wrongly. It has to take current value instead of this it takes old value**

> sample:
>   [ngmodel not updating](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxsugh?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**How to update current value to ngmodel..? Please suggest good answer**

> Reproducing procedure:

1.run sample link

2. change drop-down value or calendar value

3.see console log, current value is taken using argument but ngmodel shows old value

**Html file**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/material.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ejs-datepicker id="date" (change)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="ModelDate"> </ejs-datepicker>

<ejs-dropdownlist id='ddlelement' [dataSource]='data' [(ngModel)]='Modelvalue' placeholder='Select a game' (change)="onDropChange($event)"></ejs-dropdownlist>

{{ModelDate}}
```

**ts file**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  public ModelDate : any ;


  public data: string[] = [ 'Badminton', 'Basketball', 'Cricket', 'Football' ];
    // set a value to pre-select
    public Modelvalue: string = 'Badminton';

  onChange(args){
    // debugger         
      console.log("NgModelvalue:" + this.ModelDate);    
     console.log("Selected value:"  +args.value);
  }
  onDropChange(args){
    debugger
    // args.dataBind();
    console.log("NgModelvalue:" + this.Modelvalue);    
     console.log("Selected value:" +args.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the (change) function with (ngModelChange) function. Because updating model value is taking a bit more time and log gets printed prior.

Try this -

```
<ejs-dropdownlist id='ddlelement' [dataSource]='data' [(ngModel)]='Modelvalue' placeholder='Select a game' (ngModelChange)="onDropChange($event)"></ejs-dropdownlist>
```

It will print data whenever model value gets change.

Comment: HI @Anusha Bansal, Thanks for your valuable support..,.....!.  It works fine for me.

Comment: You are logging args.value .. Change it with args only. It will work as we have binded the function with ngModelChange

Comment: Check again. I have checked its working or show me the ejs tag code for calendar what you change in that.

Comment: <ejs-datepicker id="date" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="ModelDate"> </ejs-datepicker>

Comment: Put (ngModelChange) after ngModel like this - <ejs-datepicker id="date"  [(ngModel)]="ModelDate" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"> </ejs-datepicker>.. Now check

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour and it's connected to the change event. Basically when the change event is fired the event part of ngModel isn't updated yet.

Basically you need to use (ngModelChange) separately with [ngModel].

See more here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406

and here: [Angular 2 change event - model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150107/angular-2-change-event-model-changes)

Comment: the fact that you are new to Angular doesn't prevent you from taking some time to study what is given and try to understand it by yourself before asking for more precision (for a couple of hours instead of one minute)

Comment: OKay @Pac0, but still i didn't get clear view about my sollution.!

Answer (score 1):

For your dropdown you have used change() event. instead of change use ngModelChange().
by using ngModelChange your ngModel will update.

```
<ejs-dropdownlist id='ddlelement' [dataSource]='data' [(ngModel)]='Modelvalue' placeholder='Select a game' (ngModelChange)="onDropChange($event)"></ejs-dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you used till now?Can you please show me some code? I think property binding or two way binding [()] will solve your prbolem

Comment: I would like to mention two things here... 1)you are getting value in your ModelValue and ModelDate use {{}} this bracket in html you can see it. 2) If you want to get Value in ts file use formcontrol

Comment: If you agree then please tick mark this as a solution