# Angular2 is there a way to use a two way binding with a checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, angular, angular2-ngmodel

I want to use a two way binding for a checkbox, but if I use the `[(ngModel)]` it is showing true or false instead of the value of the checked item. Does anybody know how this is done?

If i want to use a two way binding and set it to "expression.value" in my case how do i do that:

```
<input type="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
```

I would like to bind the value of the checkbox in this case: Option 1 into the expression class.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872843/angular-2-not-giving-current-state-of-checkbox

Comment: I updated my answer. It takes into account that `expression` might not yet be set when when Angular tries to resolve the binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406,
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6311

There are different workarounds like using `event.target.checked` instead of the value from the model.

You can use

```
<input type="checkbox"  
    (change)="expression && expression.Option1=$event.target.checked ? true : undefiend"
    [ngModel]="expression?.Option1">
<input type="checkbox"  
    (change)="expression && expression.Option2=$event.target.checked ? true : undefiend"
    [ngModel]="expression?.Option2">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PBGBPj?p=preview)

Comment: As you can see it is logging the event itself: http://i66.tinypic.com/2qd4z6t.png

Comment: I updated the answer. I mentioned it in the text but forgot to update the code.

Comment: It is logging value: "on" and not Option1 in my case

Comment: Sorry, It should be `$event.target.checked`

Comment: Wait i think you do not understand what my goal is. I have got multiple checkboxes Option1, option2 etc I want to bind the checked Option into my expression class. So that if i log the value of the checked items I see the label of the checked Option1, Option2

Comment: Then change `expression.value` to `expression.Option1` and `expression?.value` to `expression?.Option1`.

Comment: input type="checkbox" (change)="expression ? expression.value=$event.target.checked : null"
                    [ngModel]="expression?.value">Option 1</a></li>

This is one of many options i want to bind **Option1** if it is checked to the class.

Comment: Not sure what do to with your last comment. You need to change `.value` to the name of the property you want to bind to.

Comment: Yes i understand that. I do not want to bind the checkbox true or false, I want to bind the value of the checked item. So if Option 3 and 4 are checked I want to see Option 3 and 4 in my log.

Comment: console log of the expression object as you can see in my first comment

Comment: How do i do this when the options are set with ngFor

Comment: Please add some code to your question that demonstrates what you actually try to accomplish. In this case I'd suggest to create a new question.